# Electric potential energy of charge relative to 2 metal plates

Tags: energy, physics, electricity

Let’s say I have a positive electric charge in middle of two plates, one is positively charged, the other one negatively with total intensity of electric field of 5 N/C.  If the charge has 2 Coulombs, and is 3 meters from positive plate and 3 meters from negative plate, it will have potential energy relative to **negative** terminal 30 Joules, right?

But what potential energy will that charge have relative to the **positive** plate? -30 Joules? And what does that even mean? Can we speak of potential energy when comparing the positive charge with positive plate?

Answer (score 0):

It represents the energy required to move the charge closer to the positive plate.  It is analogous to measuring the potential energy of a boulder at the bottom of a hill relative to the top of that hill.

Answer (score 0):

The initial force between the two charges separated by a distance d is

- F=2kQ²/d²
- Q=CU and E=1/2CU² [J]
- F(d)= E(d) * e for electric field e
- **The change in potential energy is related to the (constant) electric field by
  ΔU = −eE⋅Δd**

Now go study harder.